# why is my linked list type not recognized?

Tags: c, linked-list

This is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node * ptr;
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  ptr next;
} item;

void printList(ptr p);

int main() {
  ptr h = NULL;

}

void printList(ptr p) {
  while(p) {
    printf("%d -> \n", ptr -> data);
    ptr = ptr -> next;
  }
}
```

I get 2 errors when I compile the code:

```
error: unexpected type name 'ptr': expected expression
            printf("%d -> \n", ptr -> data);
                               ^

error: expected identifier or '('
            ptr = ptr -> next;
```

I tried to play around with all kind of changes but I don't understand why I'm getting these errors.

Comment: zOMG, Please, fix a style. And don't use this brain damaged typedef.

Comment: highly recommend not hiding pointers in `typedef`s

Comment: I have to use `typedef` as part of my course.

Comment: Still, don't hide pointers in typedefs. Use `typedef struct node { ... } Node`, then just use `Node *`. Also, don't use typedefs names later for variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's a lesson in using overly-generic type names.

You've defined `ptr` as a type -- the type for a pointer to an item -- and in most cases you use it that way.  But on the two lines in question, you use `ptr` as though it were the name of a variable.  The variable of type `ptr` in your code is named `p`.

Answer (score 4):

You're referring to the type of the structure member not the structure member.

```
printf("%d -> \n", ptr -> data);
ptr = ptr -> next;
```

should be

```
printf("%d -> \n", p->data);
p = p->next;
```

Answer (score 2):

> why is my linked list type not recognized?

The errors do not indicate that your type is unrecognized.  Indeed, the first expressly indicates that `ptr` is recognized as a type name.  The problem, as it says, is that an *expression*, not a type name, is required as the left operand of the `->` operator.  In particular, it looks like you want to use variable `p` rather than type `ptr` on the indicated lines.  For example,

```
p = p->next;
```